# Install Rpi-Userland on arm64 Pi 4 running Ubuntu Pi 22.04 server

Tags: server, 22.04, raspberrypi, arm64

I am trying to build tvheadend on Ubuntu Pi 22.04.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/build/tvheadend/master$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 5.15.0-1015-raspi #17-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Mon Sep 12 13:14:51 UTC 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/build/tvheadend/master$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
```

But at the end I am getting errors:

```
...
.....
.......
Markdown: docs/wizard/network.md
Markdown: docs/wizard/status.md
CC              src/docs.o
CC              tvheadend
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lprofiler: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltcmalloc: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [Makefile:712: /usr/local/src/tvheadend/build.linux/tvheadend] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/tvheadend'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:110: ffmpeg_all] Error 2
```

When I search for these files it looks like I don't have them:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls -l /usr/lib | grep profiler
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls -l /usr/lib | grep malloc  
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls -l /opt/vc/lib | grep profiler
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls -l /opt/vc/lib | grep malloc  
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

My understanding is they are rpi-userland files/utilities and I need them in 64-bit for my Pi 4 (arm64). There is a method to install an rpiuserland with the snap command, but that doesn't work for me:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo snap install rpi-userland --edge
error: snap "rpi-userland" is not available on edge for this architecture (arm64) but exists on
       other architectures (amd64, armhf).
```

I have searched around and I tried building an rpi-userland using this script but it didn't work on my system:
https://gist.github.com/satmandu/c462ab301cbe09bd6e7cf4db7f626727

Looks like there is a raspberrypi-userland source package in Jammy here...
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/+source/raspberrypi-userland
But I don't know what to do with it??

Does anyone know how to install the rpi-userland files on arm64 Ubuntu Pi server 22.04?

Any help much appreciated!

Flex

Answer (score 0):

It turns out those errors had nothing to do with rpi-userland files they were both part of `Google's gperftools profiler`.

My options were to build tvheadend with the `--disable-gperftools` build option or else to install the support for them:

```
# sudo apt install gperftools libgoogle-perftools-dev
```

**Installing rpi-userland on Ubuntu 22.04 64-bit running on a Pi 4**
As mentioned above the SNAP command does not currently work to install rpi-userland in this environment.

Furthermore currently rpi-userland is just not supported on any 64-bit OS running on a Pi 4.

You can download and cross compile the [32-bit rpi-userland sources](https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland) on your 64-bit system. [This github page](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/remove-snap-block-ubuntu-2204/https://gist.github.com/satmandu/c462ab301cbe09bd6e7cf4db7f626727) has a script `build_arm64_rpi_userland.sh` that does that. It generates a .deb file which you can then install like this:

```
# sudo dpkg -i /home/ubuntu/workdir/output/rpiuserland_54fd97a_arm64.deb
```

Initially I had some problems and needed to run these commands:

```
# sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

• Then tried again...

```
# sudo apt install libgcc1-armhf-cross
# sudo apt install libc6-armhf-cross
# sudo apt install libstdc++6-armhf-cross
# sudo dpkg -i rpiuserland_54fd97a_arm64.deb
```

The catch is that you don't get full rpi-userland functionality, some of the libraries work but not all. For instance there is no mmal support.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dpkg -L rpiuserland | grep mmal 
/opt/vc/lib/pkgconfig/mmal.pc 
/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_mmal_encode 
/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_mmal_encode/Makefile 
/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_mmal_encode/mmal_encode.c 

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dpkg -L rpiuserland | grep bcm 
/opt/vc/include/bcm_host.h 
/opt/vc/lib/libbcm_host.so 
/opt/vc/lib/pkgconfig/bcm_host.pc

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls -l /opt/vc/lib/ | grep mmal 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

For instance, none of these mmal libraries are available in /opt/vc/lib

```
libmmal_components.so
libmmal_core.so
libmmal.so
libmmal_util.so
libmmal_vc_client.so
```

In my case I was trying to build tvheadend with mmal support but the build still failed with:
`ERROR: mmal not found`
This was because the mmal stuff never got ported to the 64-bit kernel and AFAIK has been deprecated.